# iOS - Can AutoLayout make constraint like view0.height = view1.height + view2.height?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want make a constraint like `view0.height = view1.height + view2.height`. And when `view1.height` or `view2.height` changed, `view0.height` will auto changed.

It's passible in iOS AutoLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if view0 contains both view1 and view2, then you just need to provide proper constraints. Like this:

[image: view0's constraints]

[image: view1's constraints]

[image: view2's constraints]

Comment: So to achieve this, the container view's subviews must have height constraint, top and bottom sides have proper constraint to container view, right?

Comment: @tom yes, exactly